# How to open existing Azure function with csx extension at local

Tags: azure-functions

I am new to azure function, I would like to know how i can open / run an existing Azure function project which having multiple functions with .csx extension at my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.csx` file project will be present in `.cs` project of azure functions.

[image]

**You can open `.cs` project in both visual studio and visual studio code.**

1. double click on `.csproj` file which opens on visual studio.

[image]

2. Right-click on the empty space of your `csproj` in file explorer and click on Open with code.

[image]

It will open in the **VS code** which shows your `.csx` file in azure functions.

[image]

### Updated Answer

I hope you download your function project in the Azure portal. If not please follow the below steps:
If you download the function project in **site content** it doesn't contain the `.csproj`.

[image]

here is the folder structure while downloading from the **site content**

[image]

If you download the function project using the **content and visual studio project** it contains the `.csproj` which is used for building and compiling the project for changes added.

[image]

here is the folder structure while downloading from the **content and visual studio project**

[image]

Comment: Hi, Actually there is no .csproj file. I am able to open in VS code but not able to build as .csproj file not exist.

Comment: Where did you get the .csx files from?

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT, I would think he got it from the Azure Portal as the development never started in VS or VSCode.  It'll be an in browser implementation.  That's what I'm thinking anyway.

Comment: @waseemansari, Please check the updated answer.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT, Yes we got from azure Portal now we want to start in VS or VS Code or any other available.

Comment: Once you download from content and visual studio project you can open in both either VS Code or VS.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT Thank you. Now able to open in VS